# iOS7GM UINavigationBar appearance setBackgroundImage: forBarMetrics: not working in UIPopoverController

Tags: uinavigationbar, ios7, uipopovercontroller

I custom UINavigationBar BackgroundImage using UINavigationBar appearance in iOS7 gm , not working in UIPopoverController.
I used this code snippet for iOS7 gm,

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navigationBarBackgroundImage   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

The above code was setted in AppDelegate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When navigation controllers are inside popovers, their navigation bar's appearance is set to match the background of the popover.

To customize the background of the popover, you should use a custom [`UIPopoverBackgroundView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverBackgroundView_class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

Comment: Very annoying behavior. An in some cases, there are bugs that cause the translucency to fail, and the navigation bar becomes transparent. Apple, how could you release an OS in such a horrible state?

Answer (score 1):

As `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:` doesn't work while navigation controller contained in a popover and `setBackgroundColor:` works well, we can use the background image as a pattern for background color as following for a certain navigation bar:

> [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationBarBG"]]];

Or for all navigation bars:

> [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationBarBG"]]];